# How to change seekbar value when volume key is pressed in android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-seekbar

I am using fragment and in my main activity I am doing this,

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP || KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
    {
        watchLive = (WatchLive)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("watch");
        watchLive.syncVolume();
        return true;
    } 
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

And in my Fragment syncVolume() method is,

```
public void syncVolume(){

        int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        int curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        volume.setMax(maxVolume);
        volume.setProgress(curVolume);
}
```

But the seekbar value is not changing/updating.
how could I change the value of seekbar when volume key is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Use seekTo like this

```
mPlayer.seekTo(progress * 1000);
```